# How to host project online that uses npm, yarn, xampp, apache, mysql?

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, web, web-hosting

I've inherited (been given from prev developer) a web project that I need to host and I'm unsure exactly how to go about doing it. In the past I've put up static websites using Namecheap.com which has been easy, but this is a more involved website.

The project uses npm and/or yarn to run, I'm not entirely sure the difference and at times they seem interchangeable. There is a backend with apache/mysql.

*The current setup*

Right now I have the project folder on my (Windows) desktop. In order to run it, first I open up Xampp control panel and make sure Apache and MySQL are running, like so:
[image]

Then I open a terminal, navigate to the project folder, and run `yarn watch`. The output looks as follows, and it automatically brings up a web browser directed to locahost:4242
[image]

That's it. Now I have to host this project online. It's got a github, and so what I did on my local machine was just clone it, and run the `npm install` commands in the readme.

Can someone point me in the right direction, or provide a step-by-step guide, for getting this website on e.g. Namecheap, where I plan to buy a URL? EDIT - I think I use something like Namecheap to buy the domain name, then a cloud website like DigitalOcean or AWS. Also for requirements, any decently modern machine should do it. Just a basic site with MySQL/Apache server, and node.js code.

Is it as simple as `ssh`ing into said server, downloading all my code, doing the `npm install`s, running Xampp on the server (after creating the DB) and then running `yarn watch`? I've never hosted a project like this on the internet before.

Thanks for any help!

(and if this isn't the right stackexchange, please point me to where would be more appropriate and I'll remove/repost!)

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing the details. The requirements for the server may depend on the code that will run on the server and the traffic you expect. A (virtual) root server would allow you to install everything you need. What exactly means you inherited the project? Has it been hosted somewhere else before? Please [edit] your question to answer or to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically someone dumped some code on me to put online, unfortunately I don't have much experience here. I got it running locally as described in the OP. Now I need to buy a particular domain and host the whole thing online. I was thinking I could use Namecheap to buy a domain, then something like DigitalOcean or AWS to host in the cloud? I need to use the Xampp that the project has. Sorry if this is too broad.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information there. I doubt that the information in your question is sufficient for a useful answer.

Comment: I've tried to do so, I can't think of what else to write. The project uses the frameworks/libraries I mentioned, and I need to host it online after buying a domain name.